How to jump to a slide in PDF preview when I click on an area of code
I'm having a problem with Beamer. I used to be able to, in the PDF preview, jump to whatever slide I was working on my TexStudio by simply clicking within the code for that slide. That feature was somehow turned off when I got my new laptop.
Does anyone know how to turn this back on?
For example, if I saw the title slide in my PDF preview, scrolled down in my code to the last slide and clicked anywhere within the code for the last slide, the PDF preview would jump to the last slide.

If I right-click in the editor, there's a “Goto PDF” entry (translated from my local language). The fourth menu entry's (“Tools”) fourth entry (“View”) does the same and can be assigned to a shortcut. I can't remember a function that does this just by a simple click in the editor.

Bottom left of pdf viewer: https://i.sstatic.net/TqkYSoJj.png

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz :O I've never seen those buttons. They also look very different on my machine.

@Qrrbrbirlbel Me neither :) Funny story: I only knew how to change these settings from the menu of the windowed pdf viewer. I went ahead and worked out how to add such an option to the right-click context menu of the embedded viewer, so that users of the embedded viewer could also use these features. I opened a pull request to merge this code only to have the maintainers point out that there are perfectly fine working buttons for this :)

@Qrrbrbirlbel The icons will depend on which icon set you use. I'm using "oxygen modern" with system icons disabled.
